# what is a best approach to handle big amount of user defined regular expressions

Tags: regex, performance, algorithm

I have a system that is parsing a stream of data, and based on subscriptions of many users it needs to filter it. These filters however can contain regular expressions and I need to make it secure enough, so that malicious users can't insert regular expressions that are purposefully CPU expensive in order to destroy the service.

I am wondering what the best approach should be,

In a different program I made I was handling this by spawning a new thread that executed the regex search, and if this thread was running longer than a limit, it was killed and entry blocked.

However this system may be processing thousands of records every minute and I can't imagine I would spawn a new thread for every single one (in fact I need to loop all subscriptions for every entry, so it could hundreds of thousands threads every minute).

Is there a better approach to handle this? Should I test the regexes using some test-data once the subscription is created? Or maybe use a separate queue for each user that get parsed in a different thread?

Also a different approach that comes to my head, is collecting statistics on how much CPU time each filter takes, and disable these that eat too much, but that doesn't really handle the "very bad" regular expressions that might need minutes of CPU time to finish

If someone was interested, I am writing it in c# but this question is rather generic and could apply to any language

Comment: I thought of blocking all nested repetition, but I'm afraid there would be too many false positives. Also, it wouldn't block things like `/.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*^/` (`O(n^16)`).

Comment: Regular expressions may be too complex for this task. How many users do you know that understand regexes? If you are building an RSS feed filtering service, wouldn't keywords be good enough?

Comment: Move the filtering part to the client.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: But that would require all of the data (thousands of records every minute) to be transmitted to every client. Probably not a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using C#, you don't need to spin off a new thread. The `Regex` constructor has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160196.aspx) that allows you to set a **timeout**. If the regex takes too long, it will abort and throw a [RegexMatchTimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexmatchtimeoutexception.aspx).

For regex engines that do not have a built-in timeout, you would probably be able to manage by spawning only one thread and reusing it, or by letting the **thread pool** allocate the threads for you.

Another thing that would be worth doing if the regexes are more than a one-shot use is to **compile** the regexes. Regexes in C# support precompiling to speed up future matches.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that... I think I will combine several answers, this is useful information

Comment: Unfortunately this is available since .Net 4.5 :( which seems too new to me (on target server I have mono)

Comment: @Petr I don't know how much of the regex engine Mono supports, but compiling the regex should still be applicable, and using the thread pool will also work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to implement your own regex engine (or find a library), use Thompson's NFA construction method and limit the number of states in each automaton (or, for better user understanding, the length of the regex, which is highly correlated). The performance of the matching algorithms is much more predictable than that of backtracking algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better if you assess the cost of running this regular expression when the user is adding a new filter. For example:

- User wants to add filter X with regular expression.
- The application should run this filter on a predefined set of data.
- If this run takes more than Y milliseconds, don't allow it to be added.
- Users with higher rank (paid service, loyal users,...) can be allowed more aggressive filters (more processing milliseconds).

Comment: It is important that the users do not know the test data, though. For, if an attacker knows you'll test on "foo", he modifies his malicious regex X to `foo|X`

Comment: @Ingo Users shouldn't know the data set; The application knows it.

Comment: Even better one generates random test data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to spawn a thread for every regex... instead, create worker threads that work through remaining regexes in a loop, logging the start of the loop at every iteration. Then, use your previous solution to kill worker threads that take too long, disable the regex and respawn the worker thread.

That way, you don't have the overhead of starting new threads all the time, but can still kill those that take too long.